# How can I make horizontal direction for last node using Tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, trees

I am using tikz to draw my tree. I want to adjust the location of last nodes as expected figure(last figure). Second, I want to locate the tree in centering on page. Could you help me to fix the latex code? Thanks

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,ulem}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=50pt,every node/.style={draw, rectangle},
attribute/.style={%
    grow=down, xshift=0cm,
    text centered, text width=1in,
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) |- ($(\tikzparentnode)!0.5!(\tikzchildnode)$) -| (\tikzchildnode)}},    
]
  \tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,->, 
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}}}
  \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center}}
  \tikzset{every level 1 node/.style={font=\small, text width=3cm}}
  \tikzset{every level 2 node/.style={font=\small, }}

  \Tree [.{{This is first level}}
    [.{This is first level} [.{AAAA \\AAAAAAAA} 
                              [.{This is left \\side of graph} 
                                 [.{First Child} ]
                                 [.{Second Child} ]]
                              [.{This is right \\side of graph} ]]
                            [.{BBBB \\BBBBBBB} 
                              [.{This is left \\side of graph} ]
                              [.{This is right \\side of graph} ]]]
    [.{Right side} [.{CCCCC \\CCCCCCCCCCCCC} 
                      [.{First Child} ]
                      [.{Second Child} ]]
                    [.{DDDDDDDDDD \\DDDDDDDDDDDDDD} 
                      [.{First Child} ]
                      [.{Second Child} ] ]]
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is my current result by using above code

[image]

My expected result is

[image]

Comment: Perhaps using `grow=right` for that last child will help?

Comment: The problem is that your "last node" choice is inconsistent. How do you tell Latex which is the last node? Because technically, the node `DDDDDDDDDDDDD` is the last node on the right.

Comment: It is last level. The last level name as 'First Child','Second Child'

Comment: Yeah, but how do you tell Latex? Because on the left side, the last child is on the 4th level. On the right side, it's the 3rd level. So it's inconsistent. Will the last child always happen on the same level in your actual document?

Comment: They have same level. I think tree method is more difficult than other

Comment: You have two first levels - one at the top of the tree and one at the top of the left branch. Trees are relatively simple structures, but they are strictly hierarchical. You can't have the first level be a child of the first level. Maybe this is an error and that's why you think the last nodes are at the same level when they are not?

Answer (score 1):

Your picture is very long. So you can rotate the same figure using \usepackage{graphicx} in the preamble and in the body immediately after \begin{figure} line write \rotatebox{90}{ and close the brace at the end of \end{tikzpicture}}. Now compile and get the chart. otherwise usepackage{lscape} and in the body \begin{landscape}.........\end{landscape}

Comment: Could you expand this a bit and format it, maybe? Right now it seems more of a comment, especially since it doesn't address a major part of the question.